# Purchase Promotional Offer (apple): Invalid signature (SKErrorDomain error 12.)

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

Firstly, we implemented basic subscriptions with free trial (introductory offer) both and all worked well. After that, we implemented the `Promotional Offer` and here's the issue:
even if we followed the guidelines provided by Apple in their documentation (from top to bottom), we are always getting the same error, which is that the "Signature is invalid.".

(`"Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (SKErrorDomain error 12.)"`

Mentions:

- the signature was implemented on our server side
- the signature is verified to be valid
- I tried with a signature generated with openssl from terminal (which was verified to be valid as well) and still didn't work
- On the UI we have a button labelled `Purchase Offer` and when that is tapped, the bottom modal from Apple is displayed correctly, with the price according to the offer
- On the mobile side, we use `swift (5)` and `SwiftyStoreKit` for handling the purchases.
- The testing was made using sandbox accounts (dev & testflight builds)

Here's the basic method to apply the offer:

```js
    
    func proceedToApplyOffer(signatureResult: PromotionalOfferSignatureResponse, username: String, completion: @escaping ((_ purchaseResult: Result<PurchaseDetails>) -> ())) {
        if #available(iOS 12.2, *) {
            
            self.getAppleProducts() {
                productsResult in
                
                // Get the apple products in order to be able to create the discount object
                
                switch productsResult {
                case .success(products: let products):
                    
                    // Create the discount object with which the purchase will be made
                    
                    guard let monthlyProduct: SKProduct = products.first(where: { $0.productIdentifier == self.monthlyProductIdentifier}) else { return }
                    let discount = SKPaymentDiscount(identifier: self.promotionalOfferIdentifier, keyIdentifier: self.keyIdentifier, nonce: signatureResult.nonce, signature: signatureResult.signature, timestamp: NSNumber(value: signatureResult.timestamp))
                    let swiftyDiscount = PaymentDiscount(discount: discount)
                    
                    self.paymentService.purchaseProductWithDiscount(product: monthlyProduct, username: username, discount: swiftyDiscount) {
                        result in
                        switch result {
                        
                        case .error(error: let skError):
                            completion(.error(skError))
                            
                        case .success(purchase: let purchaseDetails):
                            completion(.success(purchaseDetails))
                        }
                    }
                case .error(error: let error):
                    completion(.error(error))
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            debugPrint("Not available on current OS version")
        }
    }
```

I am aware that this question have been asked before (I read them all), but they didn't have any answer and I hope this one will have one, since I came to the conclusion that even the questions posted on the apple.developer forum remained unanswered.
I will appreciate any help, any idea
Thank you

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @Jovan yes, finally, I discovered that the issue was on how the signature was created on our server. I found a sample server written in node js and I used it. Here it is https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/generating_a_promotional_offer_signature_on_the_server

Comment: @Jovan also, pay attention to how you're sending the nonce when you're making the purchase. It has to have a valid UUID value, I put it like this `nonce: UUID(uuidString: nonce)`, where the nonce is the one received on the signature from our server (maybe this helps you too)

Comment: I've run into an issue where I get the same error, can somebody help me? Here's pictures of what I've done so far
https://imgur.com/a/5S2rQwC

Comment: At first sight, it looks fine, similar to how I did it. Did you check that the payment obj created has the correct productIdentifier? I've done it sth like `products.first(where: { $0.productIdentifier == self.monthlyProductIdentifier}) else { return }`. Eventually I'd try with a signature generated using the sample server here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/generating_a_promotional_offer_signature_on_the_server and check if is sth wrong with the signature generation